# Write StringIO object to csv file with newline character

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Trying to write some Chinese letters in CSV file using StringIo object.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import io

csvRow=['emp_name','Erica Meyers','中国日报网','IT']
data_temp = io.StringIO()
writer1 = csv.writer(data_temp, delimiter=',')
writer1.writerow(csvRow)
```

and data_temp object attaching to jira :

```
thisJira.add_attachment(issue=new_issue, attachment=data_temp, filename='CSVResult.csv')
```

In csv file I got this charactes:

Csv Result

[image]